# Convert XML into SQL Server rectangular resultset

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

How to shred XML shown into SQL resultset?

```
<xml>
    <registernumber>12</registernumber>
    <language name="English">
        <RegularTests>
            <RegularTest Id="05-division">
                <group>05-Counts</group>
            </RegularTest>
            <RegularTest Id="08-division">
                <group>08-Counts</group>
            </RegularTest>
            <RegularTest Id="09-division">
                <group>09-Counts</group>
            </RegularTest>
        </RegularTests>
        <groups>
            <group key="05-Counts">
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">A</word>
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">B</word>
            </group>
            <group key="08-Counts">
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">C</word>
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">D</word>
            </group>
            <group key="09-Counts">
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">E</word>
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">F</word>
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">G</word>
            </group>
        </groups>
    </language>
    <language name="Japanese">
        <RegularTests>
            <RegularTest Id="05-division">
                <group>05-Counts</group>
            </RegularTest>
            <RegularTest Id="08-division">
                <group>08-Counts</group>
            </RegularTest>
            <RegularTest Id="09-division">
                <group>09-Counts</group>
            </RegularTest>
        </RegularTests>
        <groups>
            <group key="05-Counts">
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">か</word>
            </group>
            <group key="08-Counts">
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">か</word>
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">か</word>
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">か</word>
            </group>
            <group key="09-Counts">
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">か</word>
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">か</word>
            </group>
        </groups>
    </language>
    <language name="Spanish">
        <RegularTests>
            <RegularTest Id="05-division">
                <group>05-Counts</group>
            </RegularTest>
            <RegularTest Id="08-division">
                <group>08-Counts</group>
            </RegularTest>
            <RegularTest Id="09-division">
                <group>09-Counts</group>
            </RegularTest>
        </RegularTests>
        <groups>
            <group key="05-Counts">
                <word Dated="09/19/2013">Д</word>           
                <word Dated="09/19/2013">Д</word>           
                <word Dated="09/19/2013">Д</word>           
            </group>
            <group key="08-Counts">
                <word Dated="09/19/2013">Д</word>           
                <word Dated="09/19/2013">Д</word>           
            </group>
            <group key="09-Counts">
                <word Dated="09/19/2013">Д</word>           
                <word Dated="09/19/2013">Д</word>           
                <word Dated="09/19/2013">Д</word>           
                <word Dated="09/19/2013">Д</word>                           
            </group>
        </groups>
    </language>
</xml>
```

Since the XML tags are nested, I was not able to get the executed output (ie) every attribute values need brought under respective parent tag with a SQL Server query.

This is an example of how the SQL Server select output needs to be like:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: @PrawinArumughan, While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt implementation of it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: i am using Microsoft SQL 2019,Desired output this the Image , Actually i want to covert the given XML into SQL Output ,Sample data is XML tag, which is already mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution. It is using multiple `CROSS APPLY` clauses to simulate relationships and `UNION ALL` clause to shape different XML fragments into a desired output.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<xml>
    <registernumber>12</registernumber>
    <language name="English">
        <RegularTests>
            <RegularTest Id="05-division">
                <group>05-Counts</group>
                <group>06-Counts</group> 
                <group>07-Counts</group>
            </RegularTest>
            <RegularTest Id="08-division">
                <group>08-Counts</group>
            </RegularTest>
            <RegularTest Id="09-division">
                <group>09-Counts</group>
            </RegularTest>
        </RegularTests>
        <groups>
            <group key="05-Counts">
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">A</word>
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">B</word>
            </group>
            <group key="08-Counts">
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">C</word>
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">D</word>
            </group>
            <group key="09-Counts">
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">E</word>
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">F</word>
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">G</word>
            </group>
        </groups>
    </language>
    <language name="Japanese">
        <RegularTests>
            <RegularTest Id="05-division">
                <group>05-Counts</group>
            </RegularTest>
            <RegularTest Id="08-division">
                <group>08-Counts</group>
            </RegularTest>
            <RegularTest Id="09-division">
                <group>09-Counts</group>
            </RegularTest>
        </RegularTests>
        <groups>
            <group key="05-Counts">
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">か</word>
            </group>
            <group key="08-Counts">
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">か</word>
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">か</word>
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">か</word>
            </group>
            <group key="09-Counts">
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">か</word>
                <word Dated="03/20/2014">か</word>
            </group>
        </groups>
    </language>
    <language name="Spanish">
        <RegularTests>
            <RegularTest Id="05-division">
                <group>05-Counts</group>
            </RegularTest>
            <RegularTest Id="08-division">
                <group>08-Counts</group>
            </RegularTest>
            <RegularTest Id="09-division">
                <group>09-Counts</group>
            </RegularTest>
        </RegularTests>
        <groups>
            <group key="05-Counts">
                <word Dated="09/19/2013">Д</word>           
                <word Dated="09/19/2013">Д</word>           
                <word Dated="09/19/2013">Д</word>           
            </group>
            <group key="08-Counts">
                <word Dated="09/19/2013">Д</word>           
                <word Dated="09/19/2013">Д</word>           
            </group>
            <group key="09-Counts">
                <word Dated="09/19/2013">Д</word>           
                <word Dated="09/19/2013">Д</word>           
                <word Dated="09/19/2013">Д</word>           
                <word Dated="09/19/2013">Д</word>                           
            </group>
        </groups>
    </language>
</xml>';

SELECT @xml.value('(/xml/registernumber/text())[1]','INT') AS registernumber
    , c.value('@name','VARCHAR(30)') AS [language]
    , test.value('@Id','VARCHAR(30)') AS [RegularTest_Id]
    , grp.value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(30)') AS [RegularTest_Group]
    , NULL AS [group_key]
    , NULL AS [word_Date]
    , NULL AS [word]
FROM @xml.nodes('/xml/language') AS t(c)
    CROSS APPLY t.c.nodes('RegularTests/RegularTest') AS z(test)
    CROSS APPLY z.test.nodes('group') AS zz(grp)
UNION ALL
SELECT @xml.value('(/xml/registernumber/text())[1]','INT') AS registernumber
    , c.value('@name','VARCHAR(30)') AS [language]
    , NULL AS [RegularTest_Id]
    , NULL AS [RegularTest_Group]
    , gr.value('@key','VARCHAR(30)') AS [group_key]
    , w.value('@Dated','VARCHAR(30)') AS [word_Date]
    , w.value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(30)') AS [word]
FROM @xml.nodes('/xml/language') AS t(c)
    CROSS APPLY t.c.nodes('groups/group') AS y(gr)
    CROSS APPLY y.gr.nodes('word') AS w(w)
ORDER BY 2, 3 DESC, 5;
```

Comment: No, its not correct, if i added another item under RegularTest Id="05-division" for language name="English", that is not appearing in the result

Comment: @PrawinArumugham, please update your original post on two counts: (1) input XML and (3) real desired output, based on #1.

Comment: @PrawinArumugham, you need to update your input XML. **"...if i added another item under RegularTest Id="05-division" for language name="English"...** Otherwise, it is impossible to help you.

Comment: <RegularTest Id="05-division">
                <group>05-Counts</group>
                <group>06-Counts</group>
                <group>07-Counts</group>
 </RegularTest>

Comment: @PrawinArumugham, I updated the solution. Check it out. You really need to learn what is a minimal reproducible example.